# Disable dash docking feature in gnome shell

Tags: gnome, dock

I want to use gnome dock only as a launching panel, I don't want it to show currently opened windows. That is it should be just bookmark bar for favorite applications. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

From 17.10 onwards ubuntu ships with a dock enabled by default, you can tweak a lot of it's settings with dconf-editor. First install the package:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Now open it, then use the search icon on the titlebar to search for "dock" and click on the first result, now search again for "show-running" and turn off the switch in first result.

If you are using the default gnome session instead, you have to first install the [dash-to-dock extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/), then apply the procedure above (you can set the dock to be permanently hidden as it is by default too).

Answer (score 0):

Try these two extensions:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/17/dock/

I had tried the latter for some time and it worked ok.

Comment: how do I configure it to disable showing running applications?

Comment: I don't know. Try asking in the extension page.